# Multinominal Logistic Regression results sensitive to Encodings

Tags: encoding, logistic-regression

I am using the following logistic regression model where I have to select one label from multi-labels:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
multi_class_prediction_model = LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg', multi_class='multinomial')

x_train=[['a','b'],[...]]
y_train=[['d'],[...]]
x_train.applymap(encodings)
y_train.applymap(encodings)

encodings={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4...}
multi_class_prediction_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I encoded the labels manually to numeric integers as above. However, the prediction seems to be sensitive to numeric values of encodings! So if I change it following:

```
encodings={'a':100,'b':200,'c':300,'d':400...}
```

Then the prediction changes drastically.

Is this methodology correct?